# String validation based on a custom format

Tags: c#, regex, string, validation, format

I want to validate a string based on custom format: `(_.__,_.__)`. This should be a decimal input followed by a comma followed by another decimal input, wrapped in a parentheses—e.g.`(1.01,3.21)`. I want the string pattern to accept one and more entries—e.g.`(1.01,3.21)(3.01,4.51)...(2.1,5.6)`. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Please show what you have done so far, share your code. [Regex.IsMatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=netframework-4.8) can help.with a correct pattern

Comment: `bool isValid = Regex.Replace(input, @"\(\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+\)", "").Length == 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do the trick for your problem:
`^(?:\(\d+(?:\.\d+)?,\d+(?:\.\d+)?\))+$`
[try it out](https://regex101.com/r/gdajJU/2) 
Currently I made all capturing groups non capturing groups since I was not sure about any specific subgroups you wanted to capture.

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this is:

- Use RegEx to return the matches of the `(x,y)` pattern.
- Use the extension methods to extract the `x` and `y`.
- Check whether the `x` and `y` are of `decimal` type using `decimal.TryParse(..)` method.
- Check whether the input string contains something else other than the required pattern.

```cs
private bool IsValidInput(string input)
{
    var pattern = @"\((.*?)\s?,\s?(.*?)\)";
    var xpatt = @"\s+\(|\s+\)|\,\(|\)\,|\)\s+|\({2,}|\){2,}|^\)\(|\)\($";
    var q = Regex.Matches(input, pattern)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .SelectMany(x => x.Groups.Cast<Group>()
        .Skip(1))
        .Select(x => x.Value);

    return !Regex.IsMatch(input, xpatt)
        && q.Count() > 0 
        && input.Replace(" ","").Length 
        == (input.Count(x => x == '(' || x == ')' || x == ',') 
        + q.Sum(x => x.Length))
        && q.All(x => decimal.TryParse(x, out _));
}
```

So, the function returns:

```
(1.01, 3.21)(3.01, 4.51)(2.1, 5.6)     => true
(abc, 3.21)(3.01, 4.51)(2.1, 5.6)      => false
(3.21)(3.01, 4.51)(2.1, 5.6)           => false
1.01, 3.2 13.01, 4.51 2.1, 5.6         => false
1.01, 3.21)(3.01, 4.51)(2.1, 5.6)      => false
(1.01, 3.21)(3.01, 4.51)(2.1, 5.6      => false
1.01, 3.21)3.01, 4.51)2.1, 5.6)        => false
(1.01, 3.21)3.01, 4.51(2.1, 5.6)       => false
(1.01, 3.21)abc(3.01, 4.51)(2.1, 5.6)  => false
(1.01, 3.21)(3.01, 4.51)abc(2.1, 5.6)  => false
abc(1.01, 3.21)(3.01, 4.51)(2.1, 5.6)  => false
(1.01, 3.21)(3.01, 4.51)(2.1, 5.6)abc  => false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use

```
(?:\(\d+(?:\.\d+)?,\d+(?:\.\d+)?\))+
```

or with global flag

```
\(\d+(?:\.\d+)?,\d+(?:\.\d+)?\)
```

[First solution](https://regex101.com/r/HNx1or/3) will match your pattern 1 or more times and returns a single match. [The second](https://regex101.com/r/HNx1or/2) will match your pattern only once. However with global flag you will get all matches as separate results.

Explanation:

```
(?:                   //begin non-capturing group
  \(                  //match opening parentheses
    \d+               //match 1 or more numbers
    (?:\.\d+)?        //optionally match a dot followed by 1 or more numbers
    ,                 //match a comma
    \d+(?:\.\d+)?     //same pattern as before comma
  \)                  //match closing parentheses
)+                    //close non-capturing group, match the group 1 or more times
```